# Limit $(e^{e/x}-e^{-e/x})/(e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x})$ as x tends to zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find limit $(e^{e/x}-e^{-e/x})/(e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x})$ as x tends to zero? I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, would someone just give me a hint as to how to solve it? I tried applying L'Hopital's rule but it didn't work well and was too lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{e^{e/x}-e^{-e/x}}{e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x}}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{e^{ex}-e^{-ex}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$

Comment: On applying L'Hopital's to the RHS I get e^(ex-x+1), what should I be doing next? Please do help.

Comment: Why do insist in applying L'Hopital's rule? You have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{ex}-e^{-ex}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{(e-1)x}-e^{-(e+1)x}}{1-e^{-2x}}=\frac\infty1=\infty.$$